# blur does not fire on p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to use `blur` on td,p without any success. [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) says that

> "Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as
> input. In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended
> to include all element types."

So it should fire on p/td tags.
Here is my sample code:

```
<p>Test 2
</p>
<p>Test 1
</p>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("p").blur(function () {
            alert('blur');
        });
        
    });
</script>
```

Note however that if I try to invoke blur programatically it is firing.

```
$("p").blur();
```

I am assuming that when I click on the first p and then click anywhere else the blur should fire...
Am I missing something here?

Comment: try `$("p").trigger("blur");` guessing myself

Comment: the documentation says that blur is fired when an element loses focus.  Is clicking on the text in a paragraph sufficient to make that paragraph GAIN the focus in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blur is the opposite event of a focus event. A p tag cannot be focused unless it has a tabindex set so your p tags won't blur.

Add the `tabindex` attribute to your p tags and a blur will be fired after tabbing or clicking e.g.

```
<p tabindex="10">test 1</p>
<p tabindex="11">test 2</p>
```

focusout event: http://jsfiddle.net/b98Bs/

blur event: http://jsfiddle.net/b98Bs/1/

(If you click the p, remember to click away from it after to fire the event)

UPDATE:

I have included a second jsfiddle to show that blur, as well as focusout, events also fire with an alert displaying the text of the p element that is losing focus.

If you want the tabindex to follow the order of the elements in the document, set them both to tabindex="0": http://jsfiddle.net/b98Bs/2/

Answer (score 0):

Blur event doesn't work with elements like p. It is usually used with input text. If you focus, you can trigger event 'focus', when focus is out, it is 
a blur event. You can use blur event there. Blur event says the loss of focus.

In below example, when focus is out, color of input text changes to red. When you focus, color is yellow.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#blurr").blur(function(){
  $(this).css("color","yellow");
}); 
$("#blurr").focus(function(){
    $("#blurr").css("color","red");
  });   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="blurr" value="click Here"/>
</body>
</html>
```